# How to get value to pass parameter from combobox extjs 4

Tags: gridview, combobox, extjs4, parameter-passing

I have a combobox and a grid. On selecting a value on the combobox, I need to get that value and pass that as a parameter to my controller, so that it can update my grid. Please help. this is my store's proxy...

```
proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            scope: this,
            url: 'myController/getValue',
            extraParams: {
                State: Ext.getCmp('mycombo').getValue() //this is not possible
            },
```

and this is my combobox.

```
items: [{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    id: 'mycombo',
                    scope: this,
                    editable: false,
                    store: this.store,
                    fieldLabel: 'Select State',
                    displayField: 'State',
                    queryMode: 'remote',
                    labelWidth: 125,

                    listeners: {
                        scope: this,
                        store.load()
                    }

                    valueField: 'State'
                }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your combo box:

```
change:function (field, newValue, oldValue, options) {
    console.log('combo changed to ' + newValue + ' from ' + oldValue); 
    gridPanel.store.load({params:{State:this.value}});
}
```